# How to disable rename property preview in VS 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

After the last update (current version is 16.8.3) when I attempt to rename a variable I get blocked by a loading icon that ends up displaying usings of the current variable.

I don't mind keeping that feature on, the thing is sometimes it takes around 1-2 seconds for the loading icon to go, and only then I can proceed with the renaming.

It feels forever really when you are doing a refactor to code where sometimes lots of renamings are performed.

To keep it short, the loading icon is **blocking** renaming when using the mouse.

Any way I can switch off that feature?
[image: loading when renaming in visual studio]

Answer (score 1):

Go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced

and uncheck "Show preview for rename tracking". in Editor Help options group.

Answer (score 0):

In VS 2022 you must use the checkbox in the rename options (upper right corner after pressing f2 or ctrl+r, ctrl+r on an identifier):

[rename, preview changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6PM4.png)